# How to connect Java program with Oracle SQL developer?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to retrieve data from Oracle SQL developer and display it into the Java program.But still I couldn't connect with SQL Developer and following error is occurred when try to retrieve data.

[image]

My db connection class in program as follow,

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","dmusers","123");
```

In sql developer database connection,

[image]

Comment: looks to me like db is down

Comment: Why: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" ? Are you connecting to Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score -1):

1) First you should check you have database orcl in MySQL DB?

jdbc:mysql://localhost:1521/orcl

2) Is MySQL jdbc driver jar file added into SQL developer? If not, add it. it will work.

Comment: I just added jdbc driver jar file into SQL developer but how can I check the database orcl is in MySQL DB?

Comment: You should check it by login MySQL through command prompt.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: 
`Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");`
And makesure you have the driver file for jdbc oracle in your classpath